# Mixed design anova assumptions

Tags: anova, mixed-model

What are the assumptions that I need to consider when running a mixed design ANVOA? Let's say I have the following data set:

```
                 |       Scenario 1       |     Scenario 2         |
                 |Trial 1|Trial 2| Trial 3|Trial 1|Trial 2| Trial 3|
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
              S1 | ...
 Condition 1  S2 | ...
              S3 |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
              S5 |
 Condition 2  S6 |
              S7 |
```

Where `Condition x` is the between-subject variable, `S1, S2, ...` are the subjects, and `Scenario`s are within-subject variables, where each `Scenario` has some nested `Trial`s.

Using `lmer` I can describe this model by: `lmer(value~Condition*Scenario + (1+Scenario|Player) + (1|Scenario/Trial)`.

Taking a more traditional approach I can collapse over `Trials` so I have the a mean value for each `Scenario`.

I think I should do the following:

1. I should check Homoskedasticity per `Scenario/Trial`
2. Check for the absence of influential data points

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I do not think that Heteroskedasticity has  anything to do with ANOVA

Comment: I was following [Bodo Winter](http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial.pdf)'s tutorial.